# Узнать тип файла при скачивании по ссылке

Tags: php

Есть ссылка типа `https://site.com/docs/2342`. По этой ссылке лежит файл с неизвестным расширением (.doc, .rar, .xls или какое-нибудь другое).

Скачиваю его следующим образом

```
file_put_contents("documents/doc1", file_get_contents("https://site.com/docs/2342"));
```

В итоге я получаю в папке `documents` файл с названием `doc1`.

Каким образом я могу узнать расширение скачиваемого файла, чтобы правильно его сохранить?

Comment: Фукция `pathinfo` [Примеры тут](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Comment: @KostaB. и чем она поможет?

Comment: Возращает информацию о файле, в частности расширение. Ей, нужно только скормить путь где лежит файл.

Comment: @KostaB.ну дак вы прочитали в вопросе, что расширения у скачиваемого файла нет?

Comment: @Dima Поменяйте загаловок. Вам нужен `тип файла`, а не расширение.

Comment: @KostaB. автору нужно определить именно расширение для сохраняемого файла. Всё верно.

Comment: @vp_arth Автор пишет, что ему нужно *узнать расширение скачиваемого файла* - это так. Но это ему нужно, *чтобы правильно его сохранить* - а вот тут расширение нафиг не нужно, нужен именно MIME-тип файла. Товарищ плохо понимает, что спрашивает - обычное дело.

Comment: @vp_arth у Вас даже в ответе написано `mime-тип`. Если расширения нет, то нужен тип файла.

Comment: @KostaB. дак ответ наверное дополнить надо в таком случае, а не вопрос исправлять?

Comment: @teran `Узнать расширение файла при скачивании по ссылке`, а по факту при скачивании расширения нет. Будет првильнее `Узнать тип файла при скачивании по ссылке`. Вопроса это не меняет, только вносит ясность.

Comment: @KostaB. исправил название вопроса

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать найти нужную информацию в заголовках ответа:

```
$content = file_get_contents("https://site.com/docs/2342");
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

---

Также можно воспользоваться функцией [finfo_buffer](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.finfo-buffer.php)

```
$content = file_get_contents("https://site.com/docs/2342");
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$type =  $finfo->buffer($content);
```

Вы получите mime-тип (навроде `application/xml; charset=utf-8`).

Далее, манипулируя строкой либо по словарю известных вашему приложению mime-типов получаете расширение для сохранения.

Comment: там еще `mime_content_type()` есть

Comment: @teran, ему файл нужен, думаю ТС хочет подобрать подходящее расширение имени файла до записи в файл.

Comment: дак я и не спорю, это ж аналог вашего buffer вызова с тем же результатом

Comment: ну в смысле что, уже к сохраненному файлу